# Как закрыть само меню при клике на пункт меню?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, меню

Привет, друзья!

Можете мне помочь с закрытием контейнера меню при клике на его пункт? Есть вот такая магия на js.

```
var menuBtn = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
var menuContainer = document.getElementById('menuContainer');
var menuIconClosed = "menu-icon closed"; //class name for closed button
var menuIconOpened = "menu-icon opened"; //class name for opened button
var menuContClosed = "menu-container closed"; //class name for closed menu
var menuContOpened = "menu-container opened"; //class name for opened menu

menuBtn.onclick = function() {
    if (menuBtn.className == menuIconClosed) {
        menuBtn.className = menuIconOpened;
        menuContainer.className = menuContOpened;
    } else if (menuBtn.className == menuIconOpened) {
        menuBtn.className = menuIconClosed;
        menuContainer.className = menuContClosed;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="menu-icon closed" id="menuBtn"></span>

<div class="showMenu">Меню</div>
<nav class="menu-container closed" id="menuContainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#gototop">Главная</a></li>
<li><a href="#ourservices">Услуги агентства</a></li>
<li><a href="#aboutus">О нас</a></li>
<li class="liNoAfter"><a href="#callus">Контакты</a></li>
<div class="myCellMobile">
<div class="myCellMargin">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker myFa"></i>
<p><span>г. Усть-Лабинск, ул.Октябрьская, 78</span><br />г. Краснодар, ул. Ставропольская 312 офис 8</p>
</div></div>
<div class="myCellMobile">
<div class="myCellMarginPhone">
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
<p class="ios_reset"><span class="nonono">+7 (918) 344-10-05</span><br />info@ricit.ru</p>
</div></div>
<li class="forcall"><span class="modal_btn">Заказать звонок</span></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
.menu-icon{display:block;font-size:0;background:none;border:none;width:30px;height:25px;position:relative;cursor:pointer;top:20px;left:20px} .menu-icon,.menu-icon:before,.menu-icon:after{border-top:3px solid #fbfbfb;-webkit-transition: all .3s;-moz-transition: all .3s;transition: all .3s} .menu-icon:before, .menu-icon:after{position:absolute;content:"";display:block;left:0;right:0;} .menu-icon:before{top:7px;width:20px} .menu-icon:after{top:17px;width:15px} .menu-icon.opened{border-top-color:transparent} .menu-icon.opened:after{-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);transform: rotate(45deg);top:12px} .menu-icon.opened:before{-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);transform: rotate(-45deg);top:12px}
/*styles for menu container*/
.menu-container {padding-top: 20px;width:300px;} .menu-container ul{list-style: none;padding: 0;margin: 0} .menu-container li{margin-bottom:10px;} .menu-container a{display: block;padding: 10px 0;color: #fff;background: #ccc;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif, arial;} .menu-container.closed{display:none} .menu-container.opened{display:block;background:#accae8;width:100%;box-shadow:0 10px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);} .showMenu{display:block!important;font-weight:300;color:#fff;font-size:14px;margin:-2px 0px 0px 60px;}.menu-container ul li, .menu-container ul li a{display:block!important;width:130px;background:none;padding:0px 0px 15px 5px!important;text-align:left;font-size:14px!important}.menu-container ul{padding:30px 0!important}.menu-container ul li.forcall{display:none!important} .menu-container ul li:after{display:none}
/* Показываем обратный звонок в полосе меню */
.onlyMobileShow{display:block!important;position:absolute;top:0px;right:5px;color:#fff;    padding:16px 0 10px 10px} .onlyMobileShow:hover{background:#97B2CC;cursor:pointer} span.modal_btn{font-size:12px!important;font-weight:normal!important} .dontShowMob{display:none}
}
```

Взято было с интернета потому, что сам в JS ни капли не силен; есть те, кто напишет как это можно воссоздать?)

Comment: в скрипте вроде есть закритие меню?

Comment: а сss случайно не было?)

Comment: Добавил выше)))

Comment: ну кстати он там работает. Код треш если честно) он он работает только  на маленьких экранах хз почему + иконки меню совсем не видно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var menuBtn = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
//Находим наш блок с меню
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var menuContainer = document.getElementById('menuContainer');
var menuIconClosed = "menu-icon closed"; //class name for closed button
var menuIconOpened = "menu-icon opened"; //class name for opened button
var menuContClosed = "menu-container closed"; //class name for closed menu
var menuContOpened = "menu-container opened"; //class name for opened menu
//Вешает клики на документ
//Проверяемклики в обертке для меню
menu.onclick = function(e) {
    //Проверяем объект клика - если кнопка меню запускаем функцию
    if(e.target ==  menuBtn) closeOrOpenMenu();
    //Если клик был не на ссилке не делаем ничего
    if(e.target.tagName != 'A') return;
    else closeOrOpenMenu();//Иначе закрываем меню
    
    //Функция для удобства
    function closeOrOpenMenu(){
      if (menuBtn.className == menuIconClosed) {
          menuBtn.className = menuIconOpened;
          menuContainer.className = menuContOpened;
      } else if (menuBtn.className == menuIconOpened) {
          menuBtn.className = menuIconClosed;
          menuContainer.className = menuContClosed;
      }
     }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
.menu-icon{display:block;font-size:0;background:none;border:none;width:30px;height:25px;position:relative;cursor:pointer;top:20px;left:20px} .menu-icon,.menu-icon:before,.menu-icon:after{border-top:3px solid #fbfbfb;-webkit-transition: all .3s;-moz-transition: all .3s;transition: all .3s} .menu-icon:before, .menu-icon:after{position:absolute;content:"";display:block;left:0;right:0;} .menu-icon:before{top:7px;width:20px} .menu-icon:after{top:17px;width:15px} .menu-icon.opened{border-top-color:transparent} .menu-icon.opened:after{-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);transform: rotate(45deg);top:12px} .menu-icon.opened:before{-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);transform: rotate(-45deg);top:12px}
/*styles for menu container*/
.menu-container {padding-top: 20px;width:300px;} .menu-container ul{list-style: none;padding: 0;margin: 0} .menu-container li{margin-bottom:10px;} .menu-container a{display: block;padding: 10px 0;color: #fff;background: #ccc;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif, arial;} .menu-container.closed{display:none} .menu-container.opened{display:block;background:#accae8;width:100%;box-shadow:0 10px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);} .showMenu{display:block!important;font-weight:300;color:#fff;font-size:14px;margin:-2px 0px 0px 60px;}.menu-container ul li, .menu-container ul li a{display:block!important;width:130px;background:none;padding:0px 0px 15px 5px!important;text-align:left;font-size:14px!important}.menu-container ul{padding:30px 0!important}.menu-container ul li.forcall{display:none!important} .menu-container ul li:after{display:none}
/* Показываем обратный звонок в полосе меню */
.onlyMobileShow{display:block!important;position:absolute;top:0px;right:5px;color:#fff;    padding:16px 0 10px 10px} .onlyMobileShow:hover{background:#97B2CC;cursor:pointer} span.modal_btn{font-size:12px!important;font-weight:normal!important} .dontShowMob{display:none}
}
body{
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<!--Сделаем обертку для меню чтобы проверять клики только в ней-->
<div id="menu">
<span class="menu-icon closed" id="menuBtn"></span>

<div class="showMenu" id="menu"menu>Меню</div>
<nav class="menu-container closed" id="menuContainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#gototop">Главная</a></li>
<li><a href="#ourservices">Услуги агентства</a></li>
<li><a href="#aboutus">О нас</a></li>
<li class="liNoAfter"><a href="#callus">Контакты</a></li>
<div class="myCellMobile">
<div class="myCellMargin">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker myFa"></i>
<p><span>г. Усть-Лабинск, ул.Октябрьская, 78</span><br />г. Краснодар, ул. Ставропольская 312 офис 8</p>
</div></div>
<div class="myCellMobile">
<div class="myCellMarginPhone">
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
<p class="ios_reset"><span class="nonono">+7 (918) 344-10-05</span><br />info@ricit.ru</p>
</div></div>
<li class="forcall"><span class="modal_btn">Заказать звонок</span></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня не скрывается

Comment: @Майкл Миллер, в ответе же работает?

Comment: нет, в ответе тоже не работает, кликал, клика по пунктам и ничего не происходило)

Comment: аааа я понял, сейчас

Comment: @Майкл Миллер, дополнил ответ

Comment: @ Horchynskyi, аааа блин, неимоверное Вам СПАСИБО, добрый человек. Помогли от души!))))) Всё четко работает))

Comment: @Майкл Миллер, и вам) Возможно в будущем потребуются сложнеё проверки, можно проверять по классам или атрибутам, а не по тагу:
if(e.target.className != 'testClass'),
if(!e.target.classList.contains("testClass") //Вернет true или false если данный клас есть в листе классов элемента
if(!e.target.hasAttribute('testAttribute');//Вернет true или false если данный атрибут есть у элемента
Подробнеё можно ознакомится отсюда:https://learn.javascript.ru/events-and-interfaces